# Convert Postgis geometry using osgeo or shapely from EWKB and back to EWKB

Tags: python-3.x, shapely, osgeo

Suppose I have the following geometry that was created using Postgis:

```
SELECT 'POINT(1 2 3 2)'::geometry
```

I would like to read the EWKB form and just rewrite it again back to EWKB (in the real world application I would make some changes to the geometry, for this example we just convert the geometry)

Using osgeo I have can do the following:

```
import binascii
from osgeo import ogr

# The geometry as EWKB as it is returned by postgis:
s = '01010000C0000000000000F03F000000000000004000000000000008400000000000000040'

binary_string = binascii.unhexlify(s)

g = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(binary_string)
print(g.ExportToIsoWkt())
print(binascii.hexlify(g.ExportToWkb()))
```

This yields:

```
POINT ZM (1 2 3 2)
b'0000000bb93ff0000000000000400000000000000040080000000000004000000000000000'
```

As you can easily see the geometry is not identical to the original one. How do I return the result such that

```
export(g) == s
```

I would be open to a solution using shapely as well, however my tests gave some problems with the M-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

I think that one culprit is the function [`ST_AsEWKB`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary) itself, since it returns the WKB representation including the SRID meta data. As the documentation states:

> The WKB spec does not include the SRID. To get the OGC WKB format use ST_AsBinary

Now, `ST_AsBinary` yields:

```
test=> SELECT ST_AsBinary(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 2 3 2)'));
                                 st_asbinary
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \x01b90b0000000000000000f03f000000000000004000000000000008400000000000000040
(1 row)
```

The first byte `01` of this [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary) indicates the endian. So here we see that by default, PostGIS returns the data in little endian format, while the default for `ExportToWkb` seems to be big endian. However, `ExportToWkb` accepts a parameter `byte_order` using which one can override this (or, one could override the default for `ST_AsBinary` with `ST_AsBinary(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 2 3 2)'), 'XDR')`):

```
import binascii
from osgeo import ogr

# The geometry as it is returned by ST_AsBinary:
s = '01b90b0000000000000000f03f000000000000004000000000000008400000000000000040'

binary_string = binascii.unhexlify(s)

g = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(binary_string)

print(g.ExportToIsoWkt())
print(binascii.hexlify(g.ExportToWkb(byte_order = 1)))
```

this yields:

```
POINT ZM (1 2 3 2)
b'01b90b0000000000000000f03f000000000000004000000000000008400000000000000040'
```

which is consistent with the output of `ST_AsBinary`...